# Is this sentence correct? Help!

Tags: grammar

“I will never be as much comfortable and happy with others anymore as I am or was with you“
Is this sentence correct? If not then which would be the grammatically correct way to say this.

P.s: I added am or was because it was for some people who I used to be friends with, and for some people who are still my friends

Comment: No it is not correct.  You would never say "as much comfortable"

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many different variations that you could use, I would express the idea that you conveyed through one of the following sentences:

In a "past" sense:

**"I will never be as comfortable and happy with others as I was with you."**

In a "present" sense:

**"I will never be as comfortable and happy with others as I am with you."**

If you want to emphasize the feelings of comfort and happiness you might want to consider using the word "nor":

**"I will never be as comfortable, nor as happy, with others as I am with you."**

I am American, and I have seen a similar constructions widely used in both speech and writing. The answers I gave are more descriptive, rather than prescriptive, in nature.

Answer (score -1):

My happiness knows no bounds when you grace me with your presence and affection. For those of my past and present are but a faint glimmer in comparison to the bright burning star, that is yourself. You bring me comfort and joy, of which I have never felt, in every waking moment of my life, and for that, I am eternally grateful.

OR

**I have never been, nor will I ever be, as happy and comfortable with other people as I am with you.**

That said, given your "PS" note, this might be a message to a friend rather than a significant other, which means you may want to consider rephrasing:

**I have never had a friend where I've been so happy and comfortable with.**